# "tagName.className + Tab" equivalent for attributes in WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-14

**Reality:**

In WebStorm (v.10.0.4), as in many other IDEs/text editors `table.table.table-striped` + `tab` saves you some time and characters to obtain `<table class="table table-striped"></table>`.

There is similar functionality for `id` attribute: `div#one` -> `<div id="one"></div>`.

With Bootstrap this works quite good. But with Angular Material, which has many custom attributes on elements, this is not sufficient.

**Question:**

Is there a way to define in WebStorm a kind of regex similar to `<tag>.<className>` to dynamically generate tags with attributes instead of CSS classes?

**What I've done so far:**

I've looked to Live Templates, but they can define only static templates, which means I have to hardcode every possible tag-attribute pair. Also I couldn't find where the `<tag>.<className>` functionality resides in in order to build something on top of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is based on [Emmet](http://emmet.io/) abbreviations. See https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/emmet-support.html, https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/expanding-emmet-templates-with-user-defined-templates.html for more information about Emmet support in WebStorm.

In particular, to generate HTML element with certain attributes, you need using `tag_name[attr=value]` syntax,

like: `link[rel=prefetch title="Hello world"]` to generate `<link rel="prefetch" href="" title="Hello world">`

Comment: emmet.io is a fantastic read at the end of the day! Additional thanks for the links. This is exactly what I needed (although I knew it, but forgot about it).